# How to efficiently sort a recursively defined Stack?

Tags: sorting, recursion, stack

Its not a homework question I am just trying to implement a recursively defined Stack. Question is purely out of curiosity.
Is there an efficient method apart from copying the elements from Stack in array, sorting them and again pushing them on stack?

Please provide the algorithm or code (I know C/C++, Java) if you have any suggestions.

Stack definition:

```
class Stack<E>
{
    E element;
    Stack<E> topOfSubStack;
}
```

Comment: We normally forgive quite a bit in terms on language, since there are people here who don't sport English as their primary language. But this is just _painful_ to read. It's like you've gone out of your way to speak some sort of pidgin variant. Please _try_ to make it understandable, we'll fix this one up for free :-)

Comment: sorry but know i have edited the sms shortcuts.

Comment: Ah, that explains it...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that access to the stack is sequential (no random access iterators), then an algorithm similar to ones used to sort lists, such as std::list::sort would work. Example C code that uses a global static array of pointers to list (it could be allocated and then passed as a parameter). For C++, the array and functions could be part of a class.

```
#define NUMLISTS 32                     /* number of lists */
typedef unsigned long long UI64;

typedef struct NODE_{
struct NODE_ * next;
UI64 data;
}NODE;

typedef struct LIST_{
NODE *first;
}LIST;

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      data                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static LIST aList[NUMLISTS];            /* array of lists */

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      SortList                                                        */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void SortList(LIST *pList)
{
NODE * pNode;
LIST mList;                             /* merged list */
int i;

    if(pList == NULL)                   /* check for null ptr */
        return;

    /* merge nodes into aList[] */
    while(NULL != (pNode = GetFirstNode(pList))){
        MergeNode(pNode);
    }

    /* find 1st non empty aList[] */
    for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i].first == NULL); i++);
    if(i >= NUMLISTS){                  /* if all empty */
        pList->first = NULL;            /*   return null list */
        return;
    }

    pList->first = aList[i].first;      /* plist = aList[i] */
    aList[i].first = NULL;              /* clear aList[i] (optional) */

    for(i++; i < NUMLISTS; i++){        /* merge remaining aList[] */
        if(aList[i].first != NULL){
            MergeLists(&mList, &aList[i], pList);
            pList->first = mList.first;
        }
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      MergeNode   merge a node into the array of lists                */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void MergeNode(NODE *pNode)
{
LIST sList;                             /* source list */
LIST mList;                             /* merged list */
int i;

    if(pNode == NULL)                   /* return if null ptr */
        return;

    sList.first = pNode;                /* src list = node */

    /* merge into array */
    for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i].first != NULL); i++){
        MergeLists(&mList, &aList[i], &sList);
        sList.first = mList.first;
    }
    if(i == NUMLISTS)                   /* update array */
        i--;
    aList[i].first = sList.first;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      MergeLists  dst = merge(src1, src2)                             */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void MergeLists(LIST *plDst, LIST *plSrc1, LIST *plSrc2)
{
NODE **ppDst, *pSrc1, *pSrc2;           /* node ptrs */

    ppDst = &(plDst->first);
    pSrc1 = GetFirstNode(plSrc1);       /* init ptrs to nodes */
    pSrc2 = GetFirstNode(plSrc2);

    while(1){
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            ppDst = &(pSrc2->next);
            /* if end of src2, dst = rest of src1 */
            if(NULL == (pSrc2 = GetFirstNode(plSrc2))){
                pSrc1->next = plSrc1->first;
                *ppDst = pSrc1;
                plSrc1->first = NULL;
                break;
            }
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            ppDst = &(pSrc1->next);
            /* if end of src1, dst = rest of src2 */
            if(NULL == (pSrc1 = GetFirstNode(plSrc1))){
                pSrc2->next = plSrc2->first;
                *ppDst = pSrc2;
                plSrc2->first = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the list is not recursively defined.
I don't understand why did you have array of lists.

Comment: It's a merge sort that uses an array of lists. The number of nodes for each aList[i] = 2^i. The nodes are merged into the array one at a time, then when all nodes are merged into the array, the array is merged to produce a single list. All operations are sequential access. It's fast way to sort a list.